# java classpath in shell

Tags: java, shell, jar, classpath

here is a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ../../../lib
ls
MY_LIB=`pwd`

for jar in `ls $MY_LIB/*.jar`
do
    CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:""$jar" 
done
echo $CLASSPATH

cd ..

#java -jar build/libs/myproject.jar -classpath \"$CLASSPATH\"
```

run this script will print that:

```
commons-codec-1.6.jar      httpclient-4.2.1.jar        httpcore-4.2.1.jar  logback-classic-1.0.6.jar  slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar  httpclient-cache-4.2.1.jar  httpmime-4.2.1.jar  logback-core-1.0.6.jar
:/home/user/mygitproject/myproject/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/home/user/mygitproject/myproject/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/user/mygitproject/myproject/lib/httpclient-4.2.1.jar:/home/user/mygitproject/myproject/lib/httpclient-cache-4.2.1.jar:/home/user/mygitproject/myproject/lib/httpcore-4.2.1.jar:/home/user/mygitproject/myproject/lib/httpmime-4.2.1.jar:/home/user/mygitproject/myproject/lib/logback-classic-1.0.6.jar:/home/user/mygitproject/myproject/lib/logback-core-1.0.6.jar:/home/user/mygitproject/myproject/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException
    at com.test.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:223)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 1 more
```

why do i get the exception?

is the classpath wrong?

is the java -classpath using incorrect?

Comment: Without having the output of the `ls` command of your `$MY_LIB`, it is hard to tell. At a first glance, I'd say that logback is missing, but without the `ls` I cannot be sure.

Comment: @fge have update, add the ls

Comment: So, you do have logback. That is strange. On the other hand, why both logback and commons-logging?

Comment: but, i think it will not affect running, it can work normal in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

The `JoranException` is in *logback-core-1.0.6.jar* but you can not use both `-jar` and `-classpath` options.

See [java - the Java application launcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html) :

> **-jar** 
>       ...
>       When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your script, so you can debug if the class that the program is looking for is inside one of those jars:

```
for jar in $(cut --output-delimiter=" " -d":" -f2- <<< $CLASSPATH); do
    unzip -l $jar | grep "ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "'JoranException' found in $jar" 
    fi
done

# Paste the above code before the following line 
#java -jar build/libs/myproject.jar -classpath \"$CLASSPATH\"
```

If you don't get the `'JoranException' found` message, then you're missing a jar, if you get several times the same message, then you have a repeated class somewhere. If it prints only once, then comment this answer to debug it further.

By the way, in linux, you could set your `CLASSPATH` as:

```
CLASSPATH=/home/user/mygitproject/myproject/lib/*.jar
```

And it will expand to all jars contained in that directory

Comment: how to use the command with CLASSPATH=/home/user/.../*.jar ??

Comment: `java -cp .:"/home/user/mygitproject/myproject/lib/*.jar" -jar build/libs/myproject.jar`